# How can I get a volume to expand uniformily in all directions, like a nova?

Tags: physics, volumetrics, force-fields

I would like to simulate a star exploding into a nova, ie

[image]

I have a quick smoke where the density is keyframed, emitting smoke from a sphere for few frames only. I need a force that pushes this smoke in every directions, *uniformly*. Vorticity, noise, texture, collisions, high definition smoke, etc will do the job of modelizing the shape as it goes and offer nice details. I do not want to use a mesh.

But it doesn't seem to exist any force field that acts like a **sphere**, attracting or repulsing everything from a single point and *uniformly*. This is very easy programmatically so I surely missed something and I hope someone will point me to the correct feature ! Otherwise I'll have to learn a bit of python I guess.

**Wind** only pushes smoke in a single direction. I can make it a cone-wind, with an angle of 90° and both 2 directions, I can only get :

[image]
(Direction says : both Z, by the way gravity is off and the domain density and temperature parameters are 0).

I can put it to sphere of course, this is another frame but same :

[image]
No idea why it raises upwards, same params as before, but anyway this is not even a sphere.

At last what approaches the most my needs is the "force" force field, in "sphere" mode, but it is absolutely not uniform :

[image]
I don't know why it acts more on the horizontal plane. I tried to modify the domain resolution since the voxels grid contributes to non-uniformity anyway but even big resolutions end this way.

I have to mention I also tried to expand an invisible sphere used as a collider, however I cannot use this then to get the vorticity, smoke effects precisely, that I am looking for.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 3):

The smoke by default rises upwards from the emitter. To disable this, you need to set the *Density* and *Temp. Diff.* both to 0. Also disable the influence of gravity by setting *Gravity* under *Smoke Field Weights* to 0.

[image]

Here, I've also set *Dissolve* to 10 frames, to make the smoke disappear. I'm using a *Force* type force field, with *Power* set to 2<sup>*</sup>. This makes the effect falloff physically correct, by making the force proportional to inverse square of the distance from the source.

[image]

And this is the result I got.

[image]

As you can see, it doesn't spread exactly equally in all directions. However, the force, and most importantly the *Vorticity* of the smoke domain, are quite strong. The smoke will be calmer if you reduce the vorticity, and spread more slowly if you reduce the strength of the force.

<sup>*</sup><sub>Have a look at the [Blender Manual](https://www.blender.org/manual/en/physics/force_fields/introduction.html#common-field-settings) for an explanation of the *Power* and other settings.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer ! I've been quite lazy in my question I have to admit it, but the best I could obtain is this precisely, I should have done some screenshots. I missed the word for 'exploding star', I would like a nova look. Editting

Comment: Edit done, here is all I could try. I upvote your answer anyway, thanks for your time.

Comment: @Atrahasis I see. I've never tried having smoke/fire spread the way you want, so I'm not sure how to do it. However, my first thought would be using particles as a source for a point density texture rather than smoke. I'll look into it over the weekend, but I can't make any promises, since this is new territory for me as well.

Comment: Indeed, I'm trying particles, at least I easily have a spherical beginning when using a lot of them :) I still have to work on shockwave deformation now, but yet with the other answer you got me on some path.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to add particle system to the sphere, and make it emit smoke. Thanks to that you will have great level of control over the explosion. This [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E1ZzQT1VcyA) gives quite good understanding of the process.

Comment: Had not seen this one yet, seems cool ! But, I missed the correct word for 'exploding star' in my OP, I mean something like a nova or a supernova, that is why I'm looking to use wind on smoke.

Comment: I editted my question, I upvote for your time anyway, thanks.